# load from json array into object array swift

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I have array of user

```
var User:[User] = []
```

I want by alamofire and swiftyjson get info from http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
I know how to request and then i have array of json

how i can make loop through json array and create object of user then append in array `User[]`

I think my problem with loop , this is from swifty json page

```
for (index,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
    //Do something you want
}
```

how i can use it in my App?

Comment: Have you searched SO or even looked at the `Related` column? There are dozens of examples. The most important thing is that you have to analyse the structure of the JSON. `{}` represents a dictionary, `[]` an array.

Comment: @vadian yea my json struct with array [], but how i get users from it and append in my array? can you write code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use similar following code

```
for (_, subDataJSON): (String, JSON) in dataJSON {
  let u = User()
  u.name = subDataJSON["name"].stringValue
  u.id = subDataJSON["id"].intValue
  u.active = subDataJSON["active"].boolValue
  self.User.append(u)
}
```

Parse your data json in loop then at the end of loop append single user object to global class User array like that.

Then use your class scoped User array like as you want.

Comment: thanks a lot , but in parameter of for loop , What is this thing that has been added " _  and subDataJSON " ? I do not understand

Comment: meaning of '_' is you will not use the first element of (String, JSON) tuple which is the index of Array or Dictionary Json. You probably won't need to implement this variable. Is everything clear?

Comment: ok also about subDataJSON and dataJSON wher is json array and single json object?

Comment: How do I know If need to implement this variable or not? can i use all element?

Comment: Just pass your `response.result.value` from Alamofire networking closure to dataJSON variable and you are good to go.